# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Attempt to persist detached object

Tags: jpa, openjpa, apache-tomee

The entity class is

```
        package com.dunkul.entity;

            import java.io.Serializable;
            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.Table;

            @Entity
            @Table(name="employee")
            public class Book implements Serializable{

               private int id;
               private String name;

               public Book(){        
               }

               @Id

               @Column(name="Id")
               public int getId() {
                  return id;
               }

               public void setId(int id) {
                  this.id = id;
               }

               public String getName() {
                  return name;
               }

               public void setName(String name) {
                  this.name = name;
               }    
            }
```

Persisting is as follows

```
           public void addBook(Book book) {
              entityManager.persist(book);
           }
```

Getting following exception

> INFO: Using dictionary class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary" (MySQL 5.7.9-log ,MySQL
>   Connector Java mysql-connector-java-5.1.37 ( Revision:
>   09940f05b4c98150f352e787a2549f11a2e9d
>       a93 )).
>       Nov 16, 2015 2:08:03 PM null
>       INFO: Connected to MySQL version 5.5 using JDBC driver MySQL Connector Java version mysql-connector-java-5.1.37 ( Revision:
>   09940f05b4c98150f352e787a2549f11a2e9da93 ).
>       Nov 16, 2015 2:08:04 PM org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil
>   handleSystemException
>       SEVERE: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: Attempt to persist detached object "com.dunkul.entity.Book@1c7cf37d".  If this is
>   a new instance, make sure any version and/or auto-generated
>        primary key fields are null/default when persisting.
>        **org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Attempt to
>   persist detached object "com.dunkul.entity.Book@1c7cf37d".  If this is
>   a
>       new instance, make sure any version and/or auto-generated primary key fields are null/default when persisting.**
>       FailedObject: com.dunkul.entity.Book@1c7cf37d
>               at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2659)
>               at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2602)
>               at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2585)

Please help. Table book has 2 columns .. Id and Name. Id is PK and NN
Name is VARCHAR(45). Default for Name is NULL.

Comment: You save a book with id 10 wich already exists

Comment: Database is not having the book with id 10. I modified 10 to 101 , 201 and getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

- the entity name is "Book", but the table that it maps to is "employee"; not an error per se, but is it intended?
- your `@Id` field needs to be generated somehow (which is what the exception tells you); you could start with adding an annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`,
- the attribute "name" of `Book` is not mapped (neither persisted, nor transient).

Comment: Thanks.. Modifying like following solved my problem.
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="Id")
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
I have one more question what if I do not want to use any @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation and set the @Id value my self?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. ID must be generated by the database, in order to be efficient. If the field "id" is not an ID, don't mark it as one.